# clickable rollover image to show text box

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, show-hide, rollover

I have 3 rollover image that i want to use it as a trigger to show text box under each images. Whenever I try to click it disappears and does not works. I'm trying to make the first one work at least.
here's my code and webpage.
http://yunjinkimdesign.com/question/practice_div.html?

the image showed on snippet is just sample I brought from google...snippet and my actual sample is different

```js
$('.top').on('click', function() {
 $parent_box = $(this).closest('.box');
 $parent_box.siblings().find('.bottom').hide();
 $parent_box.find('.bottom').toggle();
});
```

```css
img{
 width: 200px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
div{
 margin: 20px;
}

.container .box .top {
  padding: 12px;}


.container .box .bottom {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="top">
      <a href="?"><img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_633/cy_0/cw_1725/ch_1725/w_720/APL/uploads/2014/11/too-cute-doggone-it-video-playlist.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/7720/night-animal-dog-pet.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_633/cy_0/cw_1725/ch_1725/w_720/APL/uploads/2014/11/too-cute-doggone-it-video-playlist.jpg'"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given `href=?` in the anchor, Just replace the `?` to `#` or remove href attribute from anchor and your code will run as you want.

```
<a href="#"><img src="lib/2.png" onmouseover="this.src='lib/papa.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='lib/2.png'"></a>
```

```js
$('.top').on('click', function() {
  $parent_box = $(this).closest('.box');
  $parent_box.siblings().find('.bottom').hide();
  $parent_box.find('.bottom').toggle();
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div {
  margin: 20px;
}
.container .box .top {
  padding: 12px;
}
.container .box .bottom {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="top">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_633/cy_0/cw_1725/ch_1725/w_720/APL/uploads/2014/11/too-cute-doggone-it-video-playlist.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/7720/night-animal-dog-pet.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_633/cy_0/cw_1725/ch_1725/w_720/APL/uploads/2014/11/too-cute-doggone-it-video-playlist.jpg'">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```